# GDAL create Grid brings invalid Grid on the first run

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal

I am playing around with gdal and numpy to create a random grid in QGIS. The following code sniplet creates an grid an tries to load into QGIS. But the the result layer is invalid. If I run the script a second time, right after the first run, the layer is created and loaded without any problem...do I miss something in my code sniplet?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

fn = "d:/newgrid.tif"
rasterband = np.random.random((10,10))
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = driver.Create(fn, xsize=10, ysize=10, bands=1, eType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rasterband)
rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(fn)
```

The error message on the first run is:  Invalid Layer : GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset d:/newgrid.tif:          `d:/newgrid.tif' not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: d:/newgrid.tif

Comment: Looks very similar to https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py (row #110->) but have a look also yourself.

Comment: Compared with https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-raster-from-array FlushCache() is missing

Comment: Great, that was missing. You can put it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to
https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#create-raster-from-array FlushCache() is missing.